# INSERT com SELECT Aleatório

Tags: sql, vba, microsoft-access

Tenho uma tabela com diversas informações e uma outra vazia.

Preciso fazer um INSERT nessa tabela vazia com apenas uma informação da outra tabela, porem o SELECT tem que ser aleatório.

Estou usando a seguinte linha no VBA:

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_Sorteio SELECT TOP 1 RE, Name_Employee, Case_Number, [Date], [Time], Supervisor, Comment, Client ORDER BY Rnd(Case_Number)"
```

Porem obtive a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: erro VBA]

Lembrando, estou usando Access 2013.

Comment: Bom dia caique, como assim select aleatório? tentou colocar variáveis no select?

Comment: Tentou :    ...  order by rnd"

Comment: Luiz, no caso acima não tinha FROM table no SELECT, porem ainda não está 100%. O ORDER BY rnd(Case_Number) server para pegar um numero aleatorio na tabela do select e inserir na tabela sorteio. Porem preciso definir no WHERE uma range de datas, mas não está funcionando. Não sei se é o Rnd() que não funciona com WHERE ou algum outro problema.

Comment: `SELECT` aleatório? Como assim?? Na sua _query_ falta um `FROM` especificando a tabela de onde está a ir buscar a informação.

Comment: @caiquelcn, conseguiu caminhar com o problema? a resposta ajudou??

Answer (score 2):

Adicionei a cláusula `FROM` que estava faltando e passei a filtrar o `Case_Number` ao invés de ordenar o resultado por ele; veja se o comando abaixo resolve:

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_Sorteio SELECT TOP 1 RE, Name_Employee, Case_Number, [Date], [Time], Supervisor, Comment, Client FROM tbl_Sorteio WHERE Case_Number = Rnd(Case_Number)"
```